# GL(n) and PGL(n) as affine algebraic groups

Tags: algebraic-geometry, group-schemes

I have seen diverse methods of defining the underlying variety of the linear algebraic groups $GL_n$ and $PGL_n$. I was then asking myself, if we could define them the following way:
$GL_n = \mathrm{Spec\ Aut}(\mathbb{A}^n)$ and $PGL_{n+1}=\mathrm{Spec\ Aut}(\mathbb{P}^n)$.

This seems to easy to be true and I have seen nobody do it.

Comment: What do you mean with $Aut(\Bbb{A}^n)$ ? $(x,y)\to (x+y^2,y)$ is an automorphism of $k[x,y]$. For $Aut(\Bbb{P}^n)$ it is true that it is $PGL_{n+1}$ though I don't know how you put a variety structure on $Aut(\Bbb{P}^n)$.

Comment: Oh well for the 1rst one, it seems like you are right.
Well $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{P}^n)$ has the canonical $k$-algebra structure with the addition and composition. Then taking $\mathrm{Spec}$ gives us a $k$-algebra

Comment: $Aut(\Bbb{P}^n)$ embeds into $PGL(O_{\Bbb{P}^n}(1))$ as a group, the latter is $PGL_{n+1}$, but I'm not sure what is $Aut(\Bbb{P}^n)$ and the embedding from a variety structure point of view. Also is your title claiming that $PGL_{n+1}$ is (isomorphic to) an affine variety ?

Comment: Yes it is. I remember seeing it is. Because typically your realise $PGL_{n}$ as the quotient $GL_n/G_m$ and since the two are affine and the latter is normal into the first one, then the quotient is affine.

Comment: Over an algebraically closed field $PGL_n = PSL_n = SL_n / \langle \zeta_n \rangle$. The coordinate ring of $SL_n$ is $k[x_{11},\ldots,x_{nn}]/(\det(x)-1)$ and that of $SL_n/\langle \zeta_n\rangle$ is the subring fixed by the automorphism $x_{ij}\to \zeta_n x_{ij}$, finitely generated by the $\prod_{l=1}^n x_{a_lb_l}$, so its Spec is an affine variety.

Comment: Oh yeah. That's an easy way to describe it. Thanks !
This said, do you think that my proposition might work ? (I would still need to define the algebraic group structure, but it does not seem to hard)

Comment: Oh wait don't bother. I am dumb. $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{P}^n)$ does not admit a canonical $k$-algebra structure.